# What's meaning of &&pointer or &*(pointer_to_pointer) in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, visual-c++, c++14

```
int *p;
int **pp;
int a = 9;
p = &a;
pp = &p;

cout << "&a: " << &a
cout << "&p: " << &p
cout << "&pp: " << &pp
cout << "pp : " << pp
cout << "*pp: " << *pp
cout << "&*pp: " << &*pp
```

`&&p` and `&&pp` aren't defined in c++ so they are wrong using, but what `&*pp` is meaning? Is `&*pp` equalent to `&&a`?

When the program is starting, the result is as follows:

```
&a:   00AEFAE4
&p:   00AEFAFC
&pp:  00AEFAF0
pp :  00AEFAFC
*pp:  00AEFAE4
&*pp: 00AEFAFC (=&p ???)
```

On the other hand, why is `&*pp` equalent to `&p`?

Comment: C++ provides templates so that direct use of pointers can be avoided

Comment: Please post an example of the  code you are asking about

Comment: Too little context to make an answer. Please expand. What code generates your output? `&*pp` looks like you dereference `pp` to `p` and then take the address again so effectively it is `&p`, but can't be sure without more information.

Comment: The code is very simple, my question is; why is &*pp equalent to &p?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be, since `*pp` is `p`?

Comment: `pp = &p;` you have the address of p. When doing `&*pp` that's equal to just `pp` which is equal to `&p`.

Comment: && is not a valid operator, but either declarator of universal reference if used in templates or declarator of rvalue reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you asked what does &*pp means here pp is a double pointer which contains address of the pointer  (*p)  by writing &*pp firstly you are dereferencing value of **pp

*(pp) which will become value inside pp which is the address of pointer p 
by writing &(*pp) now you are trying to get address of the dereferenced value which is (address of p) that will ultimetely become address of p

in simple words where you use both of these operators together they cancel out each other and give you the value present in the pointer 
in this case &* will be cancelled out and you will get value of pp which is address of p 
i tried to make it as clear as i could.... hope that helps :)